# How to activate the multiplayer feature with the multitap in EA's NHL series on SNES?

Tags: snes, gaming-accessories

I tried last month to use my [Super Multitap](http://www.junctioneight.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Super-Multitap.jpg) with games like NHL 96 and NHL 97 to try 4 or 5 player action, but it didn't seem to work. Only 2 player would show up on the team select menu so I thought it was just a myth made by the internet so I gave up.

However, I recently stumbled upon [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3Tz8mi9LJY) that shows some 4-player footage at 2:57.

Did more youtube research and found [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAeSedO0a6M) that clearly shows that 5 player is possible. Did more research and [found](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Multitap) that NHL 94 is the only one with 5-player support, following years had 4-player max.

But still I don't know why I couldn't activate it, is there a special procedure to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of testing in the past months, here are the results of my research.

- NHLPA 93 doesn't seem to support more than 2-player, which was expected.
- NHL 94 Plugged in the Super Multitap with switch set to 3P-5P, and the game recognised the controllers in any port! Supports 5-Player!
- NHL 95, 96, 97 Couldn't get any game to detect the Super Multitap or any controller plugged to it, except the port representing player 2. This is weird because the available space on the side selection screen of each game makes it seem like they made enough space for 5 controllers and it is stated all over the internet that they support at least 4-players. 2 Player only.
- NHL 98 Couldn't test it because I don't own it at the moment, however I will update this answer when I'll get my hands on it!

If anyone wants to give an answer on what happens on emulator feel free to do it as it would be really appreciated to be documented a little also.

UPDATE 1:

Forgot to write that I found the original instruction manuals for these games online. Only NHL 94 has a section about the Super Multitap.

- [NHL 94 Instruction Booklet](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_SNES/manual/Formated/NHL_-94_-_1993_-_Electronic_Arts.pdf)
- [NHL 95 Instruction Booklet](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_SNES/manual/Formated/NHL_Hockey_-95_-_1994_-_Electronic_Arts.pdf)
- [NHL 96 Instruction Booklet](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_SNES/manual/Formated/NHL_-96_-_1995_-_Electronic_Arts.pdf)
- [NHL 97 Instruction Booklet](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_SNES/manual/Formated/NHL_-97_-_1996_-_Electronic_Arts.pdf)
- Couldn't find the manual for NHL 98

Comment: I would love to hear from a dev or someone who worked on these games why a seemingly planned feature available on '94 was abruptly dropped from 95 to 97 silently.